# Spark-Shell error: "spark.dynamicAllocation.{min/max}Executors must be set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying to start spark-shell after setting up Spark 1.2.1 on cloudera quick start VM. I am getting the below error.Looking for help in resolving this issue. Appreciate any quick help on this to resolve the issue. The log of the error is mentioned below:

```
16/03/03 09:40:37 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory/local-1457026830824
org.apache.spark.SparkException: spark.dynamicAllocation.{min/max}Executors must be set!
    at org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager.validateSettings(ExecutorAllocationManager.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager.<init>(ExecutorAllocationManager.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:986)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at <init>(<console>:20)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:828)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:962)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


scala>
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception is pretty clear. It seems that you've set the `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` property to `true`, but failed to set `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors`. The [spark 1.2.1 documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/configuration.html) clearly states this (from `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` description, emphasis mine):

> This requires the following configurations to be set:
>   **spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors**,
>   **spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors**, and
>   **spark.shuffle.service.enabled**

If you look at the [1.2 branch of Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala), you'll see that if you don't specify those values, the default defers to -1:

```
// Lower and upper bounds on the number of executors. These are required.
private val minNumExecutors = conf.getInt("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", -1)
private val maxNumExecutors = conf.getInt("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", -1)
```

This behavior has changed. If you look at the [updated 1.6 branch of Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala), you'll see that they defer to `0` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, respectively:

```
// Lower and upper bounds on the number of executors.
private val minNumExecutors = conf.getInt("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", 0)
private val maxNumExecutors = conf.getInt("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", 
                                           Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

This simply means, you need to add these either to the `SparkConf` settings, or to any other configuration file you're providing to the spark-shell:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", minExecutors)
  .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", maxExecutors)
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Yuval. Your response has helped resolve the issue. I have done the following to resolve the issue. In the spark-default.conf file, i have set the spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false and also ensured HDFS is started before invoking the spark shell. This has started spark context successfully. However i am not able to start the spark-sql. The error it says is unable to connect to the hive metastore. Started hive and yarn and started spark-sql but got another error and not able tostart spark-sql. Is it not possible to start spark-shell and spark-sql on spark.1.2.1 at the same time.